# How can I apply for a visa sponsored by my boyfriend

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a boyfriend who is a citizen of Switzerland. He wants me to go there for a visit in 90 days. And he's willing to pay for the expenses. But what kind of visa should I apply? Is it visa for family / friend?  or fiance?

Comment: Are you engaged to be married?

Comment: You need to explain what are your plans with this travel... Is it a tourist travel? As already asked: Are you engaged to be married? So, the visa type depending of that.

Comment: No ma'am I'm not engaged only visit him and his family for this coming June.

Comment: you don't mention where you are from, OP